# Реализация интерфейсов по ООП стандартам Java

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

Реализовать сборочную линию объектов. В данном случае - танка. 
Главный класс Main. Он вызывает классы.

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tank tank = new Tank();
        tank.assembleProduct(new InstalationProducts());
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
```

Класс Tank, с реализованным интерфейсом IAssemblyLine

```
    public class Tank implements IAssemblyLine{
    @Override
    public IProduct assembleProduct(IProduct iProduct) {

        ProductBody body = (ProductBody) new CreatureFirstPart().buildProductPart();
        iProduct.installFirstPart(body);

        ProductEngine engine = (ProductEngine) new CreatureSecondPart().buildProductPart();
        iProduct.installSecondPart(engine);

        ProductTower tower = (ProductTower) new CreatureThirdPart().buildProductPart();
        iProduct.installThirdPart(tower);

        InstalationProducts instalation = new InstalationProducts(body, engine, tower);
        System.out.println("Сэр, танк готов, сэр");

        return instalation;
    }
    }
```

Дальше пойдут 4 интерфеса.

```
    public interface IAssemblyLine{
    IProduct assembleProduct(IProduct iProduct);
    }

    public interface ILineStep {
    IProductPart buildProductPart();
    }

    public interface IProduct {
    void installFirstPart(IProductPart productPart);
    void installSecondPart(IProductPart productPart);
    void installThirdPart(IProductPart productPart);
    }

    public interface IProductPart {
    }
```

Дальше я просто имплетировал интерфейсы к классам сборщикам. По порядку.

Этот и следующие 2 класс получают интерфейс для поставки необходимой части в метод.

```
    public class CreatureFirstPart implements ILineStep{
    @Override
    public IProductPart buildProductPart() {
        System.out.println("Сэр, корпус прибыл, сэр");
        return new ProductBody("корпус");
    }
    }

----------

    public class CreatureSecondPart implements ILineStep {
        @Override
        public IProductPart buildProductPart() {
            System.out.println("Сэр, двигатель прибыл, сэр");
            return new ProductEngine("двигатель");
        }
    }


----------


    public class CreatureThirdPart implements ILineStep{
        @Override
        public IProductPart buildProductPart() {
            System.out.println("Сэр, башня прибыла, сэр");
            return new ProductTower("башня") ;
        }
    }
```

Теперь создаём такие классы, якобы эти детали.

```
    public class ProductBody implements IProductPart{

        String productBody;

        ProductBody(String bodyProduct) {
            this.productBody = productBody;
        }
    }

----------
    public class ProductEngine implements IProductPart{
        String productEngine;
        ProductEngine(String productEngine){this.productEngine = productEngine;}
    }

----------

    public class ProductTower implements IProductPart{
        String productTower;
        ProductTower(String productTower) {this.productTower = productTower;}
    }
```

самый большой класс, который всё устанавливает.

```
    public class InstalationProducts implements IProduct{

        IProductPart body;
        IProductPart tower;
        IProductPart engine;

        InstalationProducts(ProductBody body, ProductEngine engine, ProductTower tower){
            this.body = body;
            this.engine = engine;
            this.tower = tower;
        }

        @Override
        public void installFirstPart(IProductPart productPart) {
            System.out.println("Сэр, корпус установлен полностью, сэр");
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public void installSecondPart(IProductPart productPart) {
            System.out.println("Сэр, двигатель установлен полностью, сэр");
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public void installThirdPart(IProductPart productPart) {
            System.out.println("Сэр, башня установлена полностью, сэр");
            System.out.println();
        }

        InstalationProducts(){}
    }
```

Собственно, проблема, которую мне написали:
1) нет присваивания установленных деталей.
2) IAssemblyLine - не продукт, а его сборочная линия, поэтому если собираем мы танк, то класс типа танк должен реализовать интерфейс IProduct.

Сама задача своими словами: есть интерфейсы, которые нужно реализовать. Есть также 3 составляющие: корпус, башня, двигатель. Они приходят в метод assembleProduct, получают 3 чати и ставят их в метод продукта. После всей сборки, готовый продукт должен вернуть assembleProduct.

Помогите исправить ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чет весело получается в Main: создаём танк из ничего, а потом на это ничего ставим сразу три компонента и отчитываемся перед начальством, почему детали не по отдельности ставят, так? XD

Так-то гуглим [шаблоны проектирования][1], в частности, здесь нужен Строитель, собирающий танк из отдельных кусков и возвращающий готовый продукт и Фабрики деталей. Сейчас объясню своими словами (лень писать код, да и Java я плоховато знаю).

Итак. 4 интерфейса - сборочной линии, готового продукта, его части и сборочных линий деталей.

Сборочные линии деталей должны собирать части продукта и возвращать их.
Это требование у вас есть, но я бы рекомендовал сделать один класс сборочной линии и один класс детали. Как различать детали? По имени: getName возвращает имя части: "engine", "body", "tower". DRY, как говорится.

```
part.getName() //"tower"
```

На производстве одна сборочная линия изготавливает один тип деталей. Значит, в конструкторе сборочной линии мы должны указать, какие детали производить.

```
PartLine engineLine = new PartLine("engine");
```

Сборочные линии деталей наладили. Теперь время устанавливать сборочную линию танка. Как видно из интерфейса IProduct, она должна выполнить три действия - установить каждую деталь и получить танк.

```
Tank tank = tankAssembleLine.assembleProduct(engine, body, tower);
```

(Кстати, ваш интерфейс сборочной линии продукта не совсем подходит под задачу. Как мне кажется, сборочная линия должна собирать продукт из частей, которые в неё засунули, а не хранить в себе детали и ставить их на пустой объект. Поэтому будем считать, что assembleProduct принимает бесконечное количество частей продукта и возвращает результат.)

Настроим нашу линию на производство танков, как мы это делали со сборочными линиями частей.

```
AssembleLine tankAssembleLine = new AssembleLine("tank");
```

Предположим, что наша сборочная линия может производить не только танки, но и телевизоры, корабли, компьютеры, да все, что угодно! Тогда сборка нашего танка будет происходить с соответствии с типом линии.

Для начала линия создаёт "проект" продукта, т.е. пустой экземпляр его класса. Как узнать, какой проект создать? Мы же передаем в сборочную линию тип продукта! Значит, нужно условие:

```
type.equals("tank") //мы делаем танки, или что? Да, мы делаем танки, значит продукт - new Tank()
```

Чтобы линия могла собирать любые продукты из любого количества деталей, будем перебирать их в цикле. В теле цикла проверять, что за деталь нам подсунули (помните, getName?) и в соответствии с условием будем использовать нужные методы интерфейса продукта.

Пока отложим линию и перейдем к реализации танка. У него, как уже сказано выше, есть три метода для установки деталей. Чтобы устанавливать детали, нужно знать, куда их ставить (двигатель заместо башни, конечно, можно припаять, но результат, мягко говоря, будет не так хорошо исполнять свою задачу :D). Поэтому у танка делаем три поля IProductPart для деталей и пишем в реализации методов, что если сборочная линия выдала нам, например, двигатель, то мы его ставим на позицию для двигателя.

Эти методы сборочная линия и будет использовать для установки деталей в танк. Все, собрали продукт? Возвращаем его как результат.

Вот и все. Данное решение можно расширять для создания чего угодно, как мне кажется.

Comment: Просто в восторге от вашего объяснения) Спасибо)) вы очень круто помогли)